# How to curve multiple lines in Word 2016?

Tags: text-formatting, microsoft-word-2016

In Word 2016, on Windows 10, I can curve one line of text by going to Format/WordArt Styles:Text Effects / Follow Path:Arch.

However, if I insert more than one line of text, the letters run into each other. 
- It happens at multiple font sizes (I tried it at 9 and 14), and in multiple fonts (I tried Calibri Light and Gill Sans MT)

Current Attempts: 
- I tried to increase the line spacing and adding space after paragraph, but that has no effect on the word art style. 
- I tried changing the kerning by 1pt, and that didn't make a difference in the vertical spacing.

Right now my workaround is to create a separate text box for each item, but that is really laborious and doesn't work at all when text needs to wrap (for example, when I'm using a cross-reference to a long title).